# how to save time without time zone in postgres . i am using hibernate Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, postgresql-9.1

> ERROR: column "receipt_time" is of type time without time zone but
>   expression is of type bytea   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast
>   the expression.   Position: 490

```
private LocalTime receiptTime;
@Column(name = "receipt_time")
public LocalTime getReceiptTime() {
 return receiptTime;
}
public void setReceiptTime(LocalTime receiptTime) {
   this.receiptTime = receiptTime;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use LocalTime then you could use a Converter:

```
@Converter
public class MyConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalTime, Time> {

    @Override
    public Time convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalTime localTime) {
        if(localTime == null){
            return null;
        }

        // convert LocalTime to java.sql.Time
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime convertToEntityAttribute(Time time) {
        if(time == null){
            return null;
        }

        // convert java.sql.Time to LocalTime
    }
}
```

Then in your entity you would use:

```
@Column(name = "receipt_time")
@Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
public LocalTime getReceiptTime() {
 return receiptTime;
}
```

Comment: Also something to consider is to update Hibernate, so they work out of the box.